# How to provide permission to a specific folder

Tags: unix

Can  anyone  guide how to provide permission to  file (a.txt) & folder or directory (a)    xx-d-r-w

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a these links:

- http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml
- http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/file-permissions_94.html

Answer (score 0):

check your man pages for chmod

```
$man chmod
```